# Does 'd' actually flap?

Tags: pronunciation, flapping

> **Flapping** or **tapping**, also known as **alveolar flapping**, **intervocalic flapping**, or **t-voicing**, is a phonological process found in many dialects of English, especially North American English, Australian English and New Zealand English, by which the consonant phoneme /t/ or /d/ placed between vowels is pronounced as a voiced flap under certain conditions.

In *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping)*, it says there can be flapping with both 't' and 'd'.
But there are only examples of t-flapping on that page.

Personally, I could realize that I flap 'd' in lots of words.

For example,

> 1. "I don't know."
> 2. "forbidden"
> 3. "widen"

Do you guys flap 'd' in such words too?
Is it more common to flap it or not?

Comment: 1 no, 2 yes, 3 yes